# Witches on the wall

Tags: wordplay, connect-wall

Witches on the wall wait for the rain of answers to fall! 
[image: witches]

Comment: The letter counts confirm what I've got so far :), but I'm baffled by these. Never done this sort of puzzle before: neither cryptic clues nor connect wall

Comment: I'm not sure that these are cryptic clues in the strict sense of the tag: Such clues follow a very narrow set of rules. In particular, they should contain a definition. The clues here seem to be all wordplay or just cryptic definitions.

Comment: @MOehm, should I change the tag? Perhaps wordplay is more appropriate?

Comment: Yes, that might be a good idea. The clues are cryptic for sure and they probably involve wordplay, but they aren't really "cryptic clues".

Comment: Drat! Thought I'd completed a second group with the 2nd in last row. Got really excited then realised it was nowhere near enough letters :(

Comment: @greenglass, they are not ordered, you know? :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva I know! But my answer for Get a spa with a tea (8) is only (5) :(

Comment: @MariaDeleva - I have worked out the answer to "Get a spa with a tea (8)" but I think you've made a spelling mistake. If I am correct it should be "Get a spa with a tea (9)". I'll update my answer with what I think it is.

Comment: @greenglass, the Zorro clue was also my favourite! :) Great job!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First group

> **Foods**
>
>  • I am witch on a beach (8): sandwich
>  • Zoro hit me twice a quarter after 3. (5): pizza (pi is after 3, two zz from zorro's sword)
>  • Hand me a bag of 50 (5): bagel (L is roman numeral for 50)
>  • Get a spa with a tea (8): spaghetti (spa, get + tea). This is 9, but I think it is correct.

Next group

> **Mistake**
>
>  • Witch misses the stake (7): mistake
>  • I am in terror (5): error (is in the word terror)
>  • I are not a giraffe (5): gaffe (means a mistake, a blunder) - take the I and R (are) out of giraffe.
>  • Flair with no err (4): remove the "r" from "flair" and you have an anagram of fail, err sounds a bit like "r", could also refer to "failure" (fail + err)

Third group

> **Traits / attributes necessary to be good at something**
>
>  • Let it be rain (5): brain (B+rain) - I wasn't convinced by this, but @MOehm made a decent case for it.
>  • Say no legend (9): knowledge (say "no legend" and you hear knowledge)
>  • End the tall (6): talent (tall + end)
>  • Kill the snake (5): skill the s is like a snake, and added the kill.

Final group, least certain here:

> **Relating to living arrangements**
>
>  • Oh, no R. (5): owner (thanks for the freebee - as soon as you told me it was so obvious!)
>  • A ghost has no age (4): host (take a "g" out of ghost)
>  • Who would have guessed? (5): guest
>  • Ten ants running on the floor. (6): tenant

Comment: I've edited the spoilers with fake markup: Lines can be broken by appending two or more spaces at the end of a line and the bullet points are just bullet characters, not real lists.

Comment: Perhaps the "Let it be rain" is brain and it goes into the third group instead of honor? Anyway, good work. It looks reasonable and I wouldn't have guessed any of those, maybe except honor.

Comment: I thought it was brain for a  while, but hono(u)r seems to be a much clearer answer, and brain is something physical while the others are intangible. That said, I am not that sure of "Kill the snake", so there could still be room for brain in that group.

Comment: I don't doubt that honor is correct, just that it belongs to that group. (I took brain or brains to mean intelligence. And I think skill is good; the wordplay is rather vague overall.)

Comment: Ok, I see how that that could form a group. The question is where honor goes, if not there.

Comment: The honor one is wrong but it does sound similar to another word. Also, only the second one of the fourth group is correct, but 2 others are very close. The last in the first group is actually very close to the real answer (although not the same word).You are one the verge to crack this puzzle. :)

Comment: I took your advice on brains, @MOehm - updated my answer accordingly

Comment: The first 3 groups are correct. I apologize for the spelling mistake. The 4th group - the third answer goes for the first. 3rd and 4th - the words you actually found are correct (not the ones you are trying to make out of them).

Comment: Ah, the first of group 4 is so clear now that you've pointed it out. I should have reread what I wrote myself and I'd have seen it! Regarding the others in group 4, does that mean the answers are simply "guest" and "tenant" (they are the right number of letters now that I think about it), or do you mean I still need to make new words from the clue but haven't got the right ones yet?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean! :) Edit them in the answer and I will mark it as accepted! :)

Comment: Fixed. That was fun, even if it did take up most of my day. The Zorro clue was by far my favourite!