# A strange crazy lady and her ramblings

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, history

I met a strange lady yesterday. She started talking to me and said the weirdest thing:

> "I have been boiling cats to get cows. Six cats for a cow, you know?
>   But nothing happened."

I was wondering what she expected at all, but remained silent. She continued with the non-sense:

> "Then, my alligator's cousin, who is just three, found grain before my
>   Poisonous Snake. 5 grain seeds, to be exact."

She was definitely crazy.

> "Triethanolamine is too long, just give me a hot drink. Or three."

What was she talking about at all??
Her ramblings continued:

> "Chilli maize resembles seed from a flowering vine. I have 11 of them.
>   And did you know that sea snails produce echoless swirls? Usually in
>   groups of six and five. Karma never ignores villains, effective,
>   sharp. I have 6 kids, you know? The last is a confused mineral and is
>   4."

Thankfully, I took another path and we separated afterwards.

**But could her ramblings actually be meaningful? Or are they connected at all?**

Hint:

> Heroic wells are confused homes of sea snails.

Comment: Can we just say 'no'? :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, you can, but then you wouldn't know the answer. :)

Comment: Are there any clues possible regarding the snails?  (Or should I learn to be patient and realise that anything to do with snails will be very slow to arrive?)

Comment: @YowE3K, I posted a hint - in fact this is how the sea snails one could have been in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a partial answer, because I haven't got an answer to all ramblings.

The ramblings are ...

> ... cryptic clues. The sentences come in pairs: The first one is the clue, the second one has a number and indicates the word length.
>
>  (The clues are not standard cryptic crossword clues, though. The OP, Maria, has developed her own style of cryptic clues, which is looser than regular cryptics. See [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42487/a-special-word-play-crossword) or [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40939/witches-on-the-wall) for examples of this style.)

I have been boiling cats to get cows. Six cats for a cow, you know? But nothing happened.

> CATTLE - Cows. Sounds like kettle (boiling) and starts with CAT.

Then, my alligator's cousin, who is just three, found grain before my Poisonous Snake. 5 grain seeds, to be exact.

> CROPS - Grain. CRO from crocodile who is just three and P S, initials of Poisonous Snake. (Thanks, YowE3K.)

Triethanolamine is too long, just give me a hot drink. Or three.

> TEA - A hot drink. TEA is an abbreviation of Triethanolamine. (Thanks, Ankoganit!)

Chilli maize resembles seed from a flowering vine. I have 11 of them.

> PEPPERCORNS - The seed of a vine. Pepper (chilli) and corn (maize); I made it plural so that it is eleven letters long

And did you know that sea snails produce echoless swirls? Usually in groups of six and five.

> COWRIE SHELLS - sea snails. An anagramm of ECHOLESS SWIRLS (which gives Cowries shells) and of HEROIC WELLS as per the extra hint.

Karma never ignores villains, effective, sharp. I have 6 kids, you know?

> KNIVES - something sharp. Take the first letters of all words. (Thanks, Ankoganit!)

The last is a confused mineral and is 4.

> SALT - A mineral substance. An anagram of LAST.

What links these items is that ...

> ... they all were used as kind of payment or as replacement for or as an early form of money.

Comment: I fear that the second to last might be "knives" (take the first letters; sharp=def?).

Comment: @Ankoganit you are correct.

Comment: @MOehm, the alligator one is not interpreted correctly. The triethanolamine one has more to its logic. The others are correct and your assumption that there is more to the puzzle after you solve them all is also correct. :)

Comment: Aha, ["TEA" is an abbreviation for Triethanolamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triethanolamine)...

Comment: Thanks. I've turned this into a community wiki, so you can edit your findings directly into the post and I don't have to keep track of answers. Solving this is going to be a collaborative effort (like the last crossword from Maria) anyway. And if someone can find the overall answer and wrap the story up, they can write a new answer to get the check mark.

Comment: @MOehm, you didn't have to make it a community wiki. :) But it is your choice. :)

Comment: Alligator cousin could be Alligator peer(Alligator pear) which is avo

Comment: What about alligator grips, a cousin could be grasp which ends "asp", a poisonous snake? You could take the gr from grain?

Comment: @KateGregory that is not the answer to this clue. :) It doesn't use all of the information given in the clue.

Comment: alligator's cousin could be a crocodile, and the answer may have something to do with a crock pot?

Comment: I think that CROPS looks good: The definition is crops and 3 from crocodile and the capped up initials from Poisonous Snake look like an okay explanation.

Comment: @MOehm,, you are right. Only the sea snails are missing now.

Comment: Okay, I've added it. Crops messes up with the steak links, though: Peppercorn steak, steak knives, tea-bone steak.

Comment: If there is a "steak" theme, maybe the crops need "stakes"  ;-)  (Or maybe the cattle eat the crops and I eat the cattle for my tea (aka dinner) and I add pepper and salt and use a knife?  plus something to do with snails)

Comment: Sea Snails = SEASONING? That swirls, like a pepper grinder?   Or perhaps it is MOLLUSK and spirals, and ratios like 5/6 can mean the [Golden Spiral or Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral)?

Comment: Just maybe Sea Snails = Oyster (both molluscs) and then Sauce for 'echoless swirls' from saucers?

Comment: @jmb.mage: I believe that (6, 5) refers to the letter count in words and is not part of the clue. But I like GOLDEN RATIO, which fits the letter count, but not, as far as I can see, the wordplay.

Comment: How about Hermit Crabs for (6,5)? I believe they take up vacated shells, which could belong to sea snails?

Comment: @shree.pat18: Good try, but based on the recently added hint I think that the solution is COWRIE SHELLS.

Comment: Doh!!! Snail answer is so obvious now.  (But I would never have guessed the linking theme.)